# Cannot navigate between method calls on Android Studio native code on a Flutter project

Tags: flutter, android-studio, native-android

I have created a new Flutter project on android studio and it cannot give autocompletion nor find the definition of the android classes, like Activity. I tried everything, setting up the SDK, invalidating caches and restart Android Studio, but nothing worked. Any idea? It is very hard and slow to develop Android Java code without the IDE assistance.

I'm using Android Studio Iguana | 2023.2.1

[image: Flutter project native android code]

Comment: It's best to create a plugin project and do your method channels code there. When it's working, depend your main project on your plugin project. When opening a plugin in Android Studio (to work on the Java/Kotlin) open the **example/android** folder, rather than the top folder.